# Unable to change the width and height of UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following layout for my UIViewController that also has a UITableView.  I have tried to change the width and height of the UIImageView inside the UITableViewCell without success. I have been using the storyboard to change the width and height without any success.  The image size remains the same size whether I try to increase or decrease any of the dimensions (as in when i install the app or it on the simulator - the size of the image is always the same)

layout:

[image]

Looks Like this:

[image]

Constraints for UIImageView:

[image]

width:

[image]

Height:

[image]

Comment: you might be interested in playing with contentMode

Comment: please could you elaborate?

Comment: Please show the constraint that you have applied for image view

Comment: please see update above for the constraints

Comment: Is the cell of your tableView loaded at the right size ? (Can you see the label ? )

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the width and height constraints and change their constants values in your example change from 20 to anything , but from size inspector or by dragging a side of the imageView you won't get anything as you can't have both auto-layout and frame at the same time

[image]

Comment: not sure that i really understand.  I did what you suggested (please see above)  - even when i change the width and height constraints i am not gtting any changes to the size of the imageview - as in when i install the app the image size is the same - no change

Comment: 5pts may not be a big change to notice , can you give it say 50 as a test

Comment: i cranked it up to 60 and the image size is the same.  I am actually trying to get the image to be smaller

Comment: Can you github this so i can check it more closely ?

Comment: its strange becuase if i use a button instead (background image) i can change the size of the button - but not UIImageView.  I think I will just use the button. not ideal but i've been at this for 3 hours. giveing me a head ace.  I am afraid I don't use github.  not cool i know